# WPF Binging problems

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, wpf-controls

I have a usercontrol which datacontext is bind to a "SelectedSchedule", with a click on a button a window is open where the "SelectedSchedule" can be edited, works fine. In this window there is a combobox with some "SelectedSchedule" to choose, which SelectedItem-Property is bind to the "SelectedSchedule". When I now choose another object in the combobox it did not get the new object, just nothing happen/change.

What I'm doing wrong?

User-Control-XAML:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=SelectedSchedule.Name}" Margin="0,-6,0,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Height="32" Width="87"/>
```

User-Control-ViewModel

```
    private Schedule mSelectedSchedule;

    public Schedule SelectedSchedule
    {
        get { return mSelectedSchedule; }
        set
        {
            mSelectedSchedule = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedSchedule");
        }
    }

    public EmployeeWeekCheckButon_VM(Schedule GivenSchedule)
    {
        SelectedSchedule = GivenSchedule;
    }

    private void Edit()
    {
        Forms.Tracking.View.frmEditTracking newForm = new Forms.Tracking.View.frmEditTracking(SelectedSchedule);
        newForm.ShowDialog();
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedSchedule");
    }

    private void Delete()
    {
        SelectedSchedule = null;
    }
```

Edit-Window-XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfSchedule}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSchedule}" x:Name="cmdSchedule" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="16" Margin="17,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

Edit-Window-ViewModel:

```
    private Schedule _SelectedSchedule;

    public Schedule SelectedSchedule
    {
        get { return _SelectedSchedule; }
        set { _SelectedSchedule = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedSchedule"); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<object> _ListOfSchedule;

    public ObservableCollection<object> ListOfSchedule
    {
        get { return _ListOfSchedule; }
        set { _ListOfSchedule = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ListOfSchedule");
        }
    }

    public frmEditTracking_VM(Schedule GivenSchedule)
    {
        SelectedSchedule = GivenSchedule;
    }

    private void SaveAndClose()
    {
        SelectedSchedule.isTracked = true;
        OnClosingRequest();
    }
```

Comment: It seems that the SelectedSchedule is set correct in the EditWindow. In Debugging-Mode in the "SaveAndClose" function the SelectedSchedule has the correct new object. But after the OnClosingRequest, returning to the UserControl its set back to the "original" SelectedSchedule. Just editing the SelectedSchedule (Name, or ID) works fine, just selecting a new SelectedSchedule seems not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the binding in two-way mode

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSchedule, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

and when the dialog is closed you need to set the new value because there is no link between the dialog and the viewmodel "SelectedSchedule" property

```
newForm.ShowDialog();
SelectedSchedule = newForm.SelectedSchedule;
```

Comment: Setting the mode to TwoWay change nothing and the "newForm" has no property "SelectedSchedule" because I'm working with a ViewModel, so the ViewModel has the property. but thanks!

Comment: Sorry, you need to give an access to the dialog ViewModel's property if you want to get it back to the base ViewModel (or get it back with the "isTracked" property)

Comment: And how do i giving access? And why its working when i just  edit the object but not when i try to assign a new object?

Comment: you can add a method in the dialog's code behind like: GetSelectedSchedule() as the dialog has access to his ViewModel (and you have the DialogResult property to notify the base ViewModel if the property has changed), or pass the base ViewModel as parameter for the dialog instead of the selected schedule then made the binding like : "ViewModel.SelectedSchedule"

Comment: Edition work because both SelectedSchedule properties are referencing the same object, assignation doesn't work because you change the dialog ViewModel property and not the base ViewModel one's

Comment: thanks a lot!!! The solution was to pass the whole ViewModel instead of just the SelectedSchedule. Thank you!

Comment: As a note, the SelectedItem property binds TwoWay by default, hence setting `Mode=TwoWay` is redundant.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I was setting it all the time

Answer (score 0):

To understand why edition is working but assignation don't you can try:

```
private Schedule mSelectedSchedule2;

public Schedule SelectedSchedule2
{
    get { return mSelectedSchedule2; }
    set
    {
        mSelectedSchedule2 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedSchedule2");
    }
}

private Schedule _SelectedSchedule;

public Schedule SelectedSchedule
{
    get { return _SelectedSchedule; }
    set { _SelectedSchedule = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedSchedule"); }
}



 public EmployeeWeekCheckButon_VM(Schedule GivenSchedule)
 {
    SelectedSchedule = GivenSchedule;
    SelectedSchedule2 = GivenSchedule;
    SelectedSchedule.Name = "Test";
    Debug.WriteLine(SelectedSchedule.Name) //it's Test
    Debug.WriteLine(SelectedSchedule2.Name) //it's Test
    SelectedSchedule = new Schedule();
    SelectedSchedule.Name = "Test2";
    Debug.WriteLine(SelectedSchedule.Name) //it's Test2
    Debug.WriteLine(SelectedSchedule2.Name) //it's still Test because 
    //it's referencing the first object

 }
```

Comment: Why didn't you edit your first answer, instead of writing another one?

Comment: Is it possible to copy SelectedSchedule without beeing a reference?

Comment: Because it was easier to copy/paste from the original question than using the editing tool

Comment: Sorry, I was using the editing tool wrong, I will edit my answer next time